# How do I implement a function that generates natural numbers 1,3,5,7...?

Tags: scala, stream

How do I implement a function that generates infinite odd natural numbers 1,3,5,7...?

My attempt is:

```
def oddNats: Stream[Int] = {
  def loop(a: Int, b: Int): Stream[Int] =
  cons(a, loop(b, a + 2))
  loop(0, 1)
}
```

it has to be `def oddNats: Stream[Int] = ???`.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Stream.from(from: Int, step: Int)` :

```
def generate(): Stream[Int] = {
    Stream.from(1, 2)
  }

println(generate().take(10).toList) // this will print List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
```

Comment: how do you do it using unfold?

Answer (score 4):

As you asked in a comment how to do this with Scala's `2.13` [`Stream.unfold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html#unfold[A,S](init:S)(f:S=%3EOption[(A,S)]):CC[A]):

```
Stream.unfold(-1)(i => Some(i+2, i+2))
// immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, <not computed>)
```

and to have a glance at what it actually does:

```
Stream.unfold(-1)(i => Some(i+2, i+2)).take(10).toList
// List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
```

Though I would recommend using [@nader.h solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56684331/9297144)

Since we generate an infinite stream, the building function will only always return `Some` (`None` would mean stopping the iteration).

The unfolding function, takes an initial state (here `-1`) and keeps updating this state (right part of the optional tuple (`i+2`)) while providing at each iteration the current state (left part of the optional tuple (in this case also `i+2`))

In other words, this starts with an initial state `-1`, and then, for each iteration, you add an element based on the current state (for the first iteration the state is `-1` and you produce `-1 + 2` - left part of the optional tuple) and you also modify the state for the next iteration (for the first iteration the state is `-1` and you produce `-1 + 2` as a new state - right part of the optional tuple).

Comment: i dont quite understand how to generate infinite sequence of odd numbers. Could you please elobarate?